# How to make an image hover in each row?

Tags: grid, row, mouseevent, mousehover

I'm triying to create a table of 3 columns and 8 rows without header. I want that each row shows a different image when putting the mouse on it.
I don't get build a table with no header, I hide it but it creates a space in the line spacing and his third column is desplaced to right. I want that each column measures the same as the others.

Someone can help me?
THANKS.

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>


  <div class="row"><div style="text-align: center"><h1><span>01</span></h1></div></div>
  <div class="row"><h1><span>THISTOPIC</span></h1></div>
  <div class="row"><h1><span>Branding, web</span></h1></div>


  <div class="row"><div style="text-align: center"><h1><span>02</span></h1></div></div>
  <div class="row"><h1><span>HEPICO FEST</span></h1></div>
  <div class="row"><h1><span>Branding</span></h1></div>


  <div class="row"><div style="text-align: center"><h1><span>03</span></h1></div></div>
  <div class="row"><h1><span>CATCH UP</span></h1></div>
  <div class="row"><h1><span>Editorial</span></h1></div>

</div>


.table {
  display: grid;
 grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table>* {
  padding: 1.3px;
  position: relative; margin-left: 100px;
}

.heading {
  color: #fff;
  grid-row: header;
}

.row span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.row:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1000%;
  left: -1000%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 4px;
  width: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.row:nth-child(5n+5)::after {
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 0;
  left: -1000%;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: auto;
  top: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.row:hover::before {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried?

Comment: Of course! I never used stackoverflow, i don't know if I write it in the best way.